# Scala, 2d Array specific array selection

Tags: scala, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if there was a way to select a 3x3 array in a 20x20 array in scala. The only thing that comes to mind my mind is to do:

```
Array.slice(
Array.slice(2,5)
Array.slice(2,5)
Array.slice(2,5))
```

(it isn't completely right but it's an idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
val bigArr = Array.tabulate(20,20)(_.toString + ":" + _.toString)

val smallArr = bigArr.slice(2,5).map(_.slice(2,5))
//smallArr: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(2:2, 2:3, 2:4)
//                                     , Array(3:2, 3:3, 3:4)
//                                     , Array(4:2, 4:3, 4:4))
```